# Using anchor with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a weird problem which is difficult to describe so if I'm not making myself clear enough, let me know and I'll try and improve the question.

I'm using multiple columns. I have set the height and width of the columns and let the content flow into as many columns as it requires. I've set the viewable area to be wide enough to only show two columns at a time and have some arrows to adjust the margins to move forward or back through the content.
I want have an anchor on page 9 so I can jump directly there however if I use an anchor and click on the link I get page 7 on the left, page 8 in the middle and page 9 on the right.

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I'll include a link so you can see the problem.

The code that holds the content looks like this

```
<div class="one" id="content">
    <div id="columnified" class="two" style="width: 310px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this

```
div.one {
    height: 435px;
    width: 710px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}

#columnified {
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 310px;
}
```

The link is:
http://www.candle-light.co.uk/flickering/dragon-wings.html#three

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: And Have you tried to make the `#columnified` to `position:relative` or absolute and maybe changing the position??